# How to get references back to what they were

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nuget, gac

I installed a couple of NuGet packages to test them out

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage

http://nuget.org/packages/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning

Now everytime I run any of my asp.net razor projects I get a 500 - Internal server error.
I uninstalled the packages, but the problem persists. Apparently they blew up some references. Please help since I cannot get any work done until this is fixed. I even reinstalled VS2010 to no avail. From the look of it some mismatch between razor versions in the GAC has occured. It's not really clear to me what the error means and how to fix it, you wouldn't think you would have to deal with this kind of things when you use NuGet, shouldn't it set things back the way it was when you uninstall?

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          2/17/2013 5:29:41 PM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 2/17/2013 5:29:41 PM 
Event time (UTC): 2/17/2013 11:29:41 PM 
Event ID: 6eec3f634ae54462ba101be097587c9b 
Event sequence: 3 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/2-130056173740865604 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: G:\home\Main\Web\ 
Machine name:  

Process information: 
Process ID: 4908 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 

Exception information: 
Exception type: InvalidCastException 
Exception message: [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be
cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from
'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows
\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor
\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 
'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
Request URL: http://localhost/Base/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/TiPS/ 
Request path: /Base/LogOn 
User host address: ::1 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 9 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]& searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<FindView>b__b(IViewEngine e)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" />
<EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
<Level>3</Level>
<Task>3</Task>
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-17T23:29:41.000000000Z" />
<EventRecordID>506239</EventRecordID>
<Channel>Application</Channel>
<Computer></Computer>
<Security />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>3005</Data>
<Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
<Data>2/17/2013 5:29:41 PM</Data>
<Data>2/17/2013 11:29:41 PM</Data>
<Data>6eec3f634ae54462ba101be097587c9b</Data>
<Data>3</Data>
<Data>1</Data>
<Data>0</Data>
<Data>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/2-130056173740865604</Data>
<Data>Full</Data>
<Data>/TiPS</Data>
<Data>G:\home\Main\Web\</Data>
<Data></Data>
<Data>
</Data>
<Data>4908</Data>
<Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
<Data>IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0</Data>
<Data>InvalidCastException</Data>
<Data>[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection. Type A originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]&amp; searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]&amp; searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassc.&lt;FindView&gt;b__b(IViewEngine e)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1c.&lt;InvokeActionResultWithFilters&gt;b__19()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass6.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassb.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClasse.&lt;EndProcessRequest&gt;b__d()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)

</Data>
<Data>http://localhost/Base/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/</Data>
<Data>/Base/LogOn</Data>
<Data>::1</Data>
<Data>
</Data>
<Data>False</Data>
<Data>
</Data>
<Data>IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0</Data>
<Data>9</Data>
<Data>IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0</Data>
<Data>False</Data>
<Data>   at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory.CreateHostFromConfig(String virtualPath, String physicalPath)
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.GetHostFromConfig()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.CreateHost()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_Host()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.EnsureGeneratedCode()
at System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(String virtualPath, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerWrapper.System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager.FileExists(String virtualPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext, List`1 locations, String name, String controllerName, String areaName, String cacheKey, String[]&amp; searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, String[] locations, String[] areaLocations, String locationsPropertyName, String name, String controllerName, String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache, String[]&amp; searchedLocations)
at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassc.&lt;FindView&gt;b__b(IViewEngine e)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1c.&lt;InvokeActionResultWithFilters&gt;b__19()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass6.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassb.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__5()
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1.&lt;MakeVoidDelegate&gt;b__0()
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClasse.&lt;EndProcessRequest&gt;b__d()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I removed references to System.Web.Razor and System.Web.Webpages.Razor, then re-added version 2 of them. That seems to have fixed the problem.